# Change the order of row selected in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 columns in the table. Right now it is in below format

```
Action   Value_XML            Control_ID        Data_Value
-----------------------------------------------------------
SEARCH  <ACTION v="SEARCH"/>     SEARCH          SEARCH
SEARCH  <BROKERREF v="BZ815"/>   BROKERREF       BZ815
SEARCH  <SYSTEM v="  0"/>        SYSTEM            0
Chg     <ACTION v="Chg"/>         Chg             Chg
Chg     <BROKERREF v="BZ815"/>   BROKERREF       BZ815
Chg     <SYSTEM v="  0"/>        SYSTEM            0
```

I need the record in below format

```
Action   Value_XML            Control_ID        Data_Value
-----------------------------------------------------------         
SEARCH  <SYSTEM v="  0"/>        SYSTEM            0
SEARCH  <BROKERREF v="BZ815"/>   BROKERREF       BZ815  
SEARCH  <ACTION v="SEARCH"/>     SEARCH          SEARCH
Chg     <SYSTEM v="  0"/>        SYSTEM            0
Chg     <BROKERREF v="BZ815"/>   BROKERREF       BZ815
Chg     <ACTION v="Chg"/>         Chg             Chg
```

Note: I need the row which has same `control_id` and datavalue should be the last row for particular action column

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have an inconsistency in your table. The value for column Control_ID should be ACTION instead of SEARCH and Chg if it should be consistent with the SYSTEM and BROKERREF values. Is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: Never mind. I re-read your note.

Comment: and what should be the order of the rows where control_id and datavalue are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the end of your query:

```
ORDER BY
Action, 
CASE WHEN Control_ID = DataValue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to save this resultset in the same order to another table?. When I try to save the result in this order to another table it is not saved in the order it is fetched.

Comment: Even it was saved in some physical order (it actually is saved in order of any clustered index), the only way to guarantee order of data is with an `ORDER BY` in a select. There is no guaranteed order of returned data without an `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t
ORDER BY Action, CASE WHEN Control_ID = Data_Value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
;
```

Comment: maybe you should add another field so the order of rows that are different are sorted consistently. you can try [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/) if it works.

Comment: and OP wants the rows with control_id = data_value be the last (so it should be `THEN 1 ELSE 0`).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to return a result set ordered by `Action` and `Control_Id`:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by Action,
         choose(Control_Id, 'SYSTEM', 'BROKERREF', 'SEARCH', 'Chg');
```

Comment: I have just given a small sample data. I have millions of record in the table. It is dynamic.I cant hardcode the values. I just need to replace the first row with the last rows and vice versa for distinct action column. It is grouped by action Column.

Answer (score 0):

by taking required columns in order by and giving desc condition will yield you results output for your sample data

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Action varchar(30),value_xml varchar(30),ControlId varchar(20),Data_value varchar(20))
insert into @T (Action,value_xml,ControlId,Data_value)values ('SEARCH','<ACTION v="SEARCH"/>','SEARCH','SEARCH'),
('SEARCH','<BROKERREF v="BZ815"/>','BROKERREF','BZ815'),('SEARCH','<SYSTEM v="  0"/>','SYSTEM','0'),
('Chg','<ACTION v="Chg"/>','Chg','Chg'),('Chg','<BROKERREF v="BZ815"/>','BROKERREF','BZ815'),
('Chg','<SYSTEM v="  0"/> ','SYSTEM','0')

select * from @T
ORDER BY Action desc,value_xml desc,ControlId desc,Data_value
```